# Изменяются файлы после перезагрузки

Tags: linux, файлы

ОС Linux.
Пишу код на php после перезагрузки компьютера восстанавливается старая определенная версия файла.

Пример 
17:00 версия файла
ABC

20:00
ABCD

после перезагрузки
ABC

Тоесть файла откатывается на свое определенно состояние

Comment: есть много вариантов. От банального "проблемы файловой системы" и "какая то программа при старте все восстанавливает" до "хитрая файловая система с принудительным сбросом" или просто ssd пришел конец.

Comment: По симптомам похоже на откатку журнала ФС на место до изменений по какой-то причине, но как @KoVadim и написал, вариантов масса. Например, дата изменения файла лежит за пределами настоящего-прошлого, и ФС негодует.

Comment: Самый очевидный вариант - во время загрузки ОС на Вашем компе, файловая система грузится с флэшки (диска) в ОЗУ. Вот там Вы и редактируете этот файл. После отключения питания (перезагрузки) все исправления теряются.

Comment: Кнопку сохранить то я нажал

Comment: Можете добавит больше информации в вопросе?  Версия дистрибутива, тип и версия редактора , тип фс, вывод lsblk; mount; df -h

Comment: @Sergey и для большинства usb-ubuntu/live дистрибутивов это так и будет.

Comment: **Кнопку сохранить то я нажал** - вопрос только в том, а ГДЕ вы сохранили отредактированный файл? Скорее всего - в образе файловой системы, в реальности расположенном в ОЗУ. После отключения питания вся информация в ОЗУ стирается. Соответственно, стирается и то, что вы яко бы, сохранили.

Answer (score 1):

Была схожая проблема. Как окзалось, сохранялось в tmpfs.

Посмотрите какой тип примонтирован - mount или df