# Изменяются файлы после перезагрузки, решение не было найдено

Tags: linux, ubuntu, файлы, raspberry-pi, flash-память

Цитата другого вопроса:

---

ОС Linux. Пишу код на php после перезагрузки компьютера восстанавливается старая определенная версия файла.

Пример 17:00 версия файла ABC

20:00 ABCD

после перезагрузки ABC

### Тоесть файла откатывается на свое определенно состояние

Как отключить использование ОЗУ как файловой системы?

т.е. создал файл - он создался на диске, а не в памяти.. у меня git репозиторий полностью лёг после перезагрузки, точнее откатился на месяц назад примерно - это катастрофа!

Comment: дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/727985/178576 , информация для автора: [Что делать, если никто не отвечает на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Начнем с того, откуда у вас вообще загружается linux. И какие устройства есть в системе. Есть ли физический раздел на энергонезависимом устройстве хранения, с обычной файловой системой (ext3, например). И если у вас только флешка и она слишком мала, то возможно у вас вся система в ОЗУ, потому что на флешке места не хватает